# Simple guessing game in Clojure not working properly

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I am new to Clojure. As part of practice, I wrote a simple guessing game where the user has to guess a random number chosen by the program between 1-100. I got a basic version working (code snippet 1). Now I want to improve on this by allowing the user to enter an integer from 1 to 100. However the code that I wrote to avoid the user from entering a string is not working (code snippet 2) but the code is not working, no matter what I try.

Code snippet 1 (working)

```
(ns guessing-game2.core
     (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (let [my-number (inc (rand-int 100))]
    (println "I have a number between 1 and 100, guess it: ")
    (loop [times 1]
      (let [guess (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
        (if (= guess my-number)
          (do
            (println "You have found it in " times " tries!")
            times)

          (do
            (cond
            (< guess my-number) (println "My number is bigger, guess again: ")
            (> guess my-number) (println "My number is smaller, guess again: "))
        (recur (inc times))))))))
```

Code snippet 2 (not working)

```
(ns guessing-game.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (let [my-number (inc (rand-int 100))]
    (println "I have a number between 1 and 100, guess it: ")
    (loop [times 1]
      (let [guess (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
      (if (and (integer? guess) 
              (< guess 100))
        (if (= guess my-number)
          (do
            (println "You have found it in " times " tries!")
            times)

          (do
            (cond
              (< guess my-number) (println "My number is bigger, guess again: ")
              (> guess my-number) (println "My number is smaller, guess again: "))))

      (print "Please enter a number")
      (recur (inc times))

    )
    ))))
```

Comment: What isn't working? This is quite vague.

Comment: Running this though, I get `Too many arguments to if` on the line under `parseInt`. Your `println` and `recur` calls are a part of the `if`. I think you want them to come after the `if`.

Comment: You're passing the `print` and `recur` calls to `if` which is too many arguments. Try to consolidate your various `if`s and the `cond` into one `cond` block. That should make things clearer. Next, `Integer/parseInt` will throw an exception. Factor that our into its own function with error handling so that it matches your new `cond` semantics.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `recur` outside of the if

```
(ns guessing-game.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (let [my-number (inc (rand-int 100))]
    (println "I have a number between 1 and 100, guess it: ")
    (loop [times 1]
      (let [guess (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
      (if (and (integer? guess) 
              (< guess 100))
        (if (= guess my-number)
          (do
            (println "You have found it in " times " tries!")
            times)

          (do
            (cond
              (< guess my-number) (println "My number is bigger, guess again: ")
              (> guess my-number) (println "My number is smaller, guess again: "))))

      (print "Please enter a number")) ;; <-- moved bracket to here 
    (recur (inc times))  
    ))))
```